# Complete Binary Merkle Tree and second pre-image attack

Tags: hash-tree, 2nd-preimage-resistance

To prevent second pre-image attacks, the Merkle Tree implementations I've looked
at add a `0` prefix to the leaves and a `1` prefix to all other nodes as described
at the bottom of this link:

https://flawed.net.nz/2018/02/21/attacking-merkle-trees-with-a-second-preimage-attack/

If we assume the Merkle Tree is a Complete Binary Tree, where all the leaves are on
the same level and packed to the left, do we need to hash the leaves with
a `0` prefix? Can we instead prefix all interior nodes with the tree depth
as the article appears to hint at and not prefix the leaves? Am I missing something?

Comment: As long as you don't hash the output of a previous hash in the tree in such a way that you can simulate another node then this should be alright I think. If you store the intermediate hashes then you could have a small issue with domain separation, but I could argue that simply adding a zero or a one would not really avoid that issue either. Hopefully someone can have a more authoritative answer though; this is mainly well informed intuition.

Comment: If they are adding only to leaves they are obviously wrong there https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71313/18298